# How do I select data from two tables based on these parameters in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, procedure

What I am trying to do is create a SQL procedure that will a.) check to see if the username and password are valid, b.) if they are valid to check what security level the user has, and c.) to return the first name of the user from another table based on the foreign reference key in my login table.

Here is my table for customer/client information:

```
create table tbClients(
ClientID int primary key identity(0,1),
ClientFirstName varchar(20),
ClientLastName varchar(20),
ClientAddress varchar(60),
ClientOrigin varchar(20)
)
```

Here is my table for login information:

```
create table tbLogin(
LoginID int primary key identity(0,1),
Username varchar(20),
Password varchar(20),
UserSecurity int,
ClientID int foreign key references tbClients(ClientID)
)
```

Here is my login procedure so far:

```
create procedure spLogin(
@Username varchar(20),
@Password varchar(20)
)

as begin
 if exists (select * from tbLogin where Username = @Username and Password = @Password)
    begin


    end
end
go
```

What I want to do is if the account exists to check what security level they are, either 1 or 2, and retrieve the client's first name from the tbClient table based on the foreign key referencing ClientID.

Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you stop storing passwords in plain text. They should be hashed and salted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple [inner join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
select
    l.UserSecurity,
    c.ClientFirstName 
from tbLogin l
inner join tbClients c on
    l.ClientID = c.ClientID 
where 
   Username = @Username and 
   Password = @Password
```

It won't return any rows if there is no match.